# kerasのインストール時にエラーが発生

Tags: python

ディープラーニングのために keras および h5py を Python にインストールしようとするとエラーが発生します。
出力内容は以下のとおりです。原因が分かる方いらっしゃいますか?

**実行環境:**
Windows 10
Python 3.8.3
Anaconda 3.8.3

**実行結果:**

```
> pip install keras

Collecting keras
  Using cached Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from keras) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from keras) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from keras) (1.19.4)
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from keras) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from keras) (1.19.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\saino\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\saino\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\saino\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzko7mh8n'
       cwd: C:\Users\saino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ma0wusag\h5py_ec806bbac6bd4b828356324725747dee
  Complete output (70 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\_hl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\test_vds\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files
  running build_ext
  Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

なお、h5py のインストールを行った場合もほぼ同様のエラーが発生してしまいます。
出力内容はこちらです。

**実行結果:**

```
pip install h5py

Collecting h5py Using cached h5py-3.1.0.tar.gz (371 kB) Installing build dependencies ... done Getting requirements to build wheel ... done Installing backend dependencies ... done Preparing wheel metadata ... done Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.5 in c:\users\saino\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from h5py) (1.19.4) Building wheels for collected packages: h5py Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'c:\users\saino\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\saino\venv\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\saino\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpe632lumh' cwd: C:\Users\saino\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxl4o7wc\h5py_65fa45567c384c5495e630af04b18574 Complete output (70 lines): running bdist_wheel running build running build_py creating build creating build\lib.win32-3.8 creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py copying h5py\h5py_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py copying h5py_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl\vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl copying h5py_hl_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py_hl creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_big_endian_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_completions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_file2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_file_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5d_direct_chunk.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5pl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests copying h5py\tests_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files copying h5py\tests\data_files_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files creating build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_highlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_lowlevel_vds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds copying h5py\tests\test_vds\test_virtual_source.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds copying h5py\tests\test_vds_init_.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\test_vds copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_dset_utc.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files copying h5py\tests\data_files\vlen_string_s390x.h5 -> build\lib.win32-3.8\h5py\tests\data_files running build_ext Loading library to get version: hdf5.dll error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly error: Could not find module 'hdf5.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Comment: 先に単独で[h5py](https://pypi.org/project/h5py/)をインストールしておいてはどうでしょう？ あるいはそれよりも先に`pip`のアップグレードが必要かもしれませんが。[Errors in installing keras using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64981174/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます事前に pip install --upgrade pip は行っているのでたぶん大丈夫なはずなのですが...

Comment: さらに 64bit版のPython環境が必要なようですね。上記英語版回答の追記 `Note: make sure your python3.8 is 64bit`

Comment: あと`numpy`が必要なようですが、`numpy 1.19.4`はWindows側ライブラリの問題で使えないので`numpy 1.19.3`を入れておく(&upgradeさせない)必要があります。

Comment: pyコマンドを入力したところ、''' Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 ''' とでてきたのでおそらく32bitになってますね、64bitのものを再インストールすれば大丈夫でしょうか

Comment: 64bitは必須のようです。私のWindows 64bit Python 3.8.6環境で何時インストール/upgradeしたか忘れましたがh5py 3.1.0とkeras 2.4.3が入っています。ただしkerasをimportしようとするとTensorFlow 2.2以上が必要と出てきます。そしてTensorFlowは64bitが必須のようです。[TensorFlowは、Windows(32bit)環境上では動かないがWindows(64bit)では動く](https://qiita.com/Zerostar/items/fbaf36a29bae7f97f960) そのため64bit環境にして先にTensorFlowをインストールしておいた方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: 64bitの方をインストールし、アナコンダプロンプトの方で pip list をすると、Kerasは無事インストールされていました。実行の際 TensorFlow 2.2以上が必要とでてきたので、pip install tensorflow でこちらも無事突破できました。ちょっと別の問題が発生してまだプログラムを動かすには至っていないのですが、それはまた別の枠で質問しようと思います。ありがとうございました!